# Keno number parser

Tags: shell, parsing, batch-file

Trying to make a script that will process Keno numbers in order to perform various pattern finding operations.

Each line of data looks like this:

> 576186    15/9/2016   21:50   8   9   12  15  22  26  32  37  39  46  49  54  57  58  59  61  67  68  70  71

This is my code blatantly taken from another post on stackoverflow but modified slightly.

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%f in (Keno.txt) do (
    set line=%%f
    call :processToken
)
goto :eof

:processToken
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=   " %%a in ("%line%") do (
        echo Got one token: %%a
        set line=%%b
        pause
    )
    if not "%line%" == "" (
        goto :processToken
    )
    goto :eof
```

I'm trying to truncate the first 3 delimiters of each line before I begin processing the raw Keno numbers but I am unable to truncate using the:`~-4%` function on `%%f` or `%%a` to do this properly. I've tried various obvious methods to achieve this by doing `set string=%%f` and then `set string=%string:~-4` for example, but this doesn't work even with `!!` or `%%` characters.

Anyone who knows how to do this?

I need this:

> 576186    15/9/2016   21:50   8   9   12  15  22  26  32  37  39  46  49  54  57  58  59  61  67  68  70  71

To look like this:

> 8 9   12  15  22  26  32  37  39  46  49  54  57  58  59  61  67  68  70  71

Comment: In order for `!!` to work, you need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ("keno.txt") do (
    rem echo %%b
     set "flag="
     for %%# in (%%b) do (
         if defined flag (
             echo|set/p"=%%# "
         ) else (
            set "flag=1"
         )
     )
)
```

**EDIT:** may be easier:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3* delims= " %%a in ("keno.txt") do (
    echo %%b
)
```

Comment: Why not use `"usebackq tokens=3* delims= "`?  Then you do not need to set the flag to get rid of the first token after the colon.

Comment: @npocmaka, you could still leave the second `FOR` and the `SET /P`.  I like the dramatic affect of it looking like someone is typing it into the screen.